# subclass __module__ set to metaclass module when manually creating new class with type()

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass

In the following example, the newly created subclass ends up being the metaclass `__module__` rather than the parent classes' module.  I've only seen this happen when using `ABCMeta` so it could be something specific to that module, anyone know what might be happening?

```
In [1]: from abc import ABCMeta

In [2]: class test(metaclass=ABCMeta):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [3]: newclass = type('newclass', (test,), {})

In [4]: newclass.__module__
Out[4]: 'abc'
```

The behavior I want happens when I define the subclass in the more standard way:

```
In [5]: class subtest(test):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [6]: subtest.__module__
Out[6]: '__main__'
```

Can someone explain why this is the case and how you could, using `type`, create a new subclass with the correct `__module__` attribute inherited (e.g. `__module__=='__main__'`)?

Comment: This looks like it might be an actual bug. Very interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If no `__module__` key is present in the mapping passed to `type.__new__`, `type.__new__` determines `__module__` based on the module where the call to `type.__new__` occurs, [by looking for `__name__` in the globals of the top Python stack frame](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L2537).

When you run `newclass = type('newclass', (test,), {})`, the `type` constructor delegates to `abc.ABCMeta`, [which then calls `type.__new__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Lib/abc.py#L133) from inside the `abc` module, so `type` thinks that `__module__` should probably be `abc`.

When you write the class statement

```
class subtest(test):
    pass
```

The compiled bytecode for the class statement automatically includes a `__module__ = __name__` assignment, which uses the current module's `__name__` instead of `abc.__name__`.

If you want to control the value of `__module__` for a class created by calling `type` directly, you can set the key in the original mapping, or assign to the class's `__module__` after creation:

```
newclass = type('newclass', (test,), {'__module__': __name__})

# or

newclass = type('newclass', (test,), {})
newclass.__module__ = __name__
```

Comment: @wim. I'd imagine it's no more dangerous than allowing `abc.ABCMeta` to set it for you implicitly.

Comment: @wim. Do `__name__ = 'asdfsdaasdasd'` in the shell, then check the `__module__` of any new class you make, either with `class` or `type`. Fun stuff.

Comment: @wim: Answer expanded.

Comment: Good, +1.  Do you think there is any possible difference in the `newclass` depending on whether it received `__module__` from the namespace passed into type vs setting it afterward?

Comment: @wim: I don't think either `type` or `abc.ABCMeta` would have a problem with it, but if some other metaclass wants to use `__module__` at type creation time, it's going to need `__module__` in the original mapping. Also, if some code somehow gets access to the class object between creating it and reassigning its `__module__`, that code could see the original value of `__module__`.