# KeyError: '__module__' when creating dynamically proxy models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create dynamically proxy models with this code:

```
from django.db import models
class BaseId(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'sae'
        abstract = True
NOMENCL_LIST = ['CAT', 'CATR', 'CCR', 'ESPIC', 'GRP', 'MFT', 'NAT', 'PERSO', 'STJ', 'STJR']
class Nomenclature(BaseId):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    nom = models.CharField( max_length=250)
    
class Valeurs_nomenclature(BaseId):
    nomenclature = models.ForeignKey(Nomenclature, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='valeurs')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class NomenclatureManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(nomenclature__code=qs.model.__name__)

for nomencl in NOMENCL_LIST:
    if nomencl not in globals():
        meta = type('Meta', (BaseId.Meta,), { 'proxy':True })
        model = type(nomencl, (Valeurs_nomenclature,), # this line causes the error
                                { 'Meta':meta, 'objects':NomenclatureManager })
        globals()[nomencl] = model
```

This code raises a `KeyError` the before last line:

```
module = attrs.pop("__module__")
KeyError: '__module__'
```

When I set explicitly "**module**", it works :

```
model = type(nomencl, (Valeurs_nomenclature,),
            { 'Meta':meta, 'objects':NomenclatureManager, '__module__':'sae.models.id_models' })
```

My question: in what circumstance '**module**' is set implicitly or not ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [subclass \_\_module\_\_ set to metaclass module when manually creating new class with type()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457441/subclass-module-set-to-metaclass-module-when-manually-creating-new-class-wit)

Comment: You could specify `'__module__': __name__` so that it is more accurate.

Comment: This explanation is very interesting, but it does not really answer, at least the two lines with `type` function should behave the same. And of course you are right concerning `'__module__': __name__ `, that makes me more comfortable. Thanks !

Comment: It does answer the question "_in what circumstance 'module' is set implicitly or not ?_" If you are wondering why you get an error in your case since `type.__new__` should have set the value automatically in that case it's because Django models have a custom metaclass whose `__new__` method accesses `__module__` and this method is called before `type.__new__`

Comment: So why `meta = type('Meta', (BaseId.Meta,), { 'proxy':True })` sets `__module__` automatically ? What is the difference ?

Comment: The metaclass for `BaseId.Meta` is `type`, hence `type.__new__` is called directly which sets the `__module__`. Django models have a [custom metaclass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/07ebef566f751e172e266165071081c7614e2d33/django/db/models/base.py#L90) and if you look at the code `module = attrs.pop("__module__")` might be called before [super_new](https://github.com/django/django/blob/07ebef566f751e172e266165071081c7614e2d33/django/db/models/base.py#L118) (which is basically `type.__new__`) is called hence `__module__` is accessed before it is even set.

Comment: Ok I understand. Looking at the code make things quite clear.